# OpenGL switching between ortho and perspecive problems

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, perspective, orthographic

I've integrated a model into OpenGL and implemented some keyboard functions for example to switch between orthografic and perspective view. Also you can zoom in and out and change the camera view. Now what i've recognize is after switching to orthografic and then back to perspective the model gets a lot of issues. First one: If i now change the horizontal camera view in the perspective view the model gets lost after a time (after pressing the camera view key often). And the second issue is that i can't really zoom in and out in the orthografic view. I tried to scale my model because i thought it could be too big but this didn't helped. And I don't know why the orthografic function creates this issue in the perspective view because without ever pressing the ortho key everything works fine in the perspective view.

```
//change to perspective
case 'p':
    if (!(perspective)) {
        projection = glm::perspective(zoom, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        perspective = true;
    }
    break;

//change to ortho
case 'o':
    if (perspective) {
        projection = glm::ortho(-100.0f, 100.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f, -1000.0f, 1000.0f);
        perspective = false;
    }
    break;

// zoom out 
case '-':
    if (zoom <= 3.0236f) {
        zoom += 0.1f;
        if (perspective) { 
            projection = glm::perspective(zoom, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        }
        else {
            projection = glm::ortho(-0.1f - zoom, 0.1f + zoom, -0.1f - zoom, 0.1f + zoom, -10000.0f, 10000.0f);
        }
    }
    break;
```

The same for zoom in with changed prefixes

I hope somebody can help thank you

if you need more details or more code please let me know

Edit: 
For the first Problem the code where i'm clearing the depth buffer in the display function

```
void display()
{
       ... defined camera settings code here ....


    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // set shader param and calculate matrices
    modelView = view * modelView * model; 
    ...
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj.vertices.size());

    glutSwapBuffers(); 
}
```

what I also recognized now is that the model in the perspective view only gets lost when using the camera view changes directly after switching from the ortho view to the perspective view. If I first press zoom in/out after changing to perspective and then using camera view changes everything works fine

Comment: It might help to save the state of your matrices for either type `perspective` or `ortho` where the user decides to make the switch with the key press before you change the view. This way when they go to change it back you can load the last saved matrix.

Comment: thats a good idea thank you i'm gonna try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a greater range of scale for your ortho matrix,

```
//change to ortho
case 'o':
    if (perspective) { 
        float min = -pow(10, zoom);
        float max = pow(10, zoom);
        projection = glm::ortho(min, max, min, max, -1000.0f, 1000.0f);
        perspective = false;
    }
    break;
```

Use the same code when you zoom in / out, or better still, factor it out into a subroutine. Also, consider whether you need such huge ranges for zNear and zFar. Try with smaller numbers.

Perhaps post your first problem as a separate question

Comment: thank you very much this helped me so much! now the ortho zoom in/out is working fine! And for the first problem i'm gonna post my code where I clear the buffer in my question post.

Comment: Ok. Please consider posting your first problem as a separate question, and marking the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help again! both of my problems are solved now, I had different values in perspective zoom and in perspective mode (case 'p') that caused the model loss :)