# Zoom out doesn´t work in orthographic projection

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, projection, orthographic

I have implemented the following code in Opengl to do the zoom in and out for my model. Unfortunetly it doesn´t show as expected in orthographic projection. When I click on "+" or "-" and switch from perspective to orthogonal, then it show just one step, when I zoom in and out. When I switch from orthogonal to perspective, then It zoom in and out, when just click on "+" than it zooms in and out and the key "-" doesn´t work at all.

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(4, 4, -3), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.2f, 1000.0f);

float zoom = 0.5236f;

case 'w':
        if (!(perspective)){
            projection = glm::perspective(zoom, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
            perspective = true;
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        if (perspective){
            projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1000.0f, 1000.0f);
            perspective = false;
        }
        break;
    case '+':

        if (zoom >= 0.0236){
            if (perspective){
                //step of zooming
                zoom = zoom - 0.5; 
                zoom -= 0.1f;
                projection = glm::perspective(zoom, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f); 

            }
            else{
                //step of zooming
                zoom = zoom - 500; 
                zoom -= 0.1f;
                projection = glm::ortho(-0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -1000.0, 1000.0);

            }
        }
            break;

    case '-':
        if (zoom <= 3.0236f){
            if (perspective){
                // step of zooming
                zoom = zoom + 0.5; 
                zoom += 0.1f;
                projection = glm::perspective(zoom, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f); 

            }
            else{     
                //step of zooming
                zoom = zoom + 500; 
                zoom += 0.1f;
                projection = glm::ortho(-0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -1000.0, 1000.0);
        }
    }
    break;  
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenGL switching between ortho and perspecive problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710262/opengl-switching-between-ortho-and-perspecive-problems)

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunetly it doesn´t show as expected in orthographic projection. When I click on "+" or "-" and switch from perspective to orthogonal, then it show just one step, when I zoom in and out

That is because in your `case 's'`

```
case 's':
    if (perspective){
        projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1000.0f, 1000.0f);
        perspective = false;
    }
    break;
```

You are not conteplating the zoom factor on this switch. It only occurs when you press '+' or '-':

```
projection = glm::ortho(-0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -0.1 - zoom, 0.1 + zoom, -1000.0, 1000.0);
```

> When I switch from orthogonal to perspective, then It zoom in and out, when just click on "+" than it zooms in and out and the key "-" doesn´t work at all.

Let us say you are in orthographic view, and `zoom = 0.5236f;`. You press '-' key. Following your program, once zoom is less than 3.0236f you get in the if statement. So, your zoom becomes `zoom = 0.5236f + 500 = 500.5236`

After that, and I dont know why, you add 0.1 to it, so `zoom = 500.6236f`. Then you switch back to perspective projection. Now, every time you press '+', once zoom > 0.0236 it get decresead by 0.6f.

However, when you press '-', your zoom is about 500, which is too bigger than 3.0236f. So, you will not get inside the if statement.

As you can see your logic is fault. You need to improve it. Sorry to say that